# Injecting AngularJS Controller data to Directive for D3 Render

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

Any suggestions on how I can inject the data gathered from my Angular controller, which gets info from the API, to the Angular directive?  The plan is to render the data received into a chart using D3.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myControl">
  <d3-bars data="d3Data"></d3-bars>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
inAng.controller('myControl', function ( $scope, $http ) {
  $http.get("/getTheDatafromAPI").
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.stack = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.stack = 'Error!';
    });
});
```

Angular Directive:

```
 inAng.directive('d3Bars', ['$window', '$timeout', 'd3Service', 
   function($window, $timeout, d3Service) {
    return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
    data: '=',
    label: '@',
    onClick: '&'
  },
  link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
    d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {

      var renderTimeout;
      var margin = parseInt(attrs.margin) || 20,
          barHeight = parseInt(attrs.barHeight) || 20,
          barPadding = parseInt(attrs.barPadding) || 5;

      var svg = d3.select(ele[0])
        .append('svg')
        .style('width', '100%');

      $window.onresize = function() {
        scope.$apply();
      };


        scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
          return scope.render(newVals);
        }, true);

      scope.$watch('data', function(newData) {
        scope.render(newData);
      }, true);

      scope.render = function(data) {
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();

        if (!data) return;
        if (renderTimeout) clearTimeout(renderTimeout);

        renderTimeout = $timeout(function() {
          var width = d3.select(ele[0])[0][0].offsetWidth - margin,
              height = scope.data.length * (barHeight + barPadding),
              color = d3.scale.category20(),
              xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                  return d.score;
                })])
                .range([0, width]);

          svg.attr('height', height);

          svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
              .append('rect')
              .on('click', function(d,i) {
                return scope.onClick({item: d});
              })
              .attr('height', barHeight)
              .attr('width', 140)
              .attr('x', Math.round(margin/2))
              .attr('y', function(d,i) {
                return i * (barHeight + barPadding);
              })
              .attr('fill', function(d) {
                return color(d.score);
              })
              .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr('width', function(d) {
                  return xScale(d.score);
                });
          svg.selectAll('text')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
              .append('text')
              .attr('fill', '#fff')
              .attr('y', function(d,i) {
                return i * (barHeight + barPadding) + 15;
              })
              .attr('x', 15)
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.name + " (scored: " + d.score + ")";
              });
        }, 200);
      };
    });
  }}
}]);
```

Comment: Why are you assigning your data to the scope variable "stack" but referencing "d3Data" in your directive attribute??? Shouldn't that be referencing "stack" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My naive answer is that you are referencing the wrong variable in the data attribute of your directive. You assign the data to stack on your scope but reference d3Data in your directive markup. Seems like you meant to assign as data="stack".

```
<div ng-controller="myControl">
  <d3-bars data="stack"></d3-bars>
</div>
```

Either that, or create a d3Data variable on scope and assign your data to that, as I would not assign your error value to the same variable I am using to pass data to D3.

```
<div ng-controller="myControl">
  <d3-bars data="d3Data"></d3-bars>
</div>


inAng.controller('myControl', function ( $scope, $http ) {
  $http.get("/getTheDatafromAPI").
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.d3Data= data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.stack = 'Error!';
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer helped me to understand how this is working!